# Python script to read csv-file from `inst` folder within custom R package

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I am building a R package that uses a Python script which in turn loads internal data. Both the py-script (`load_csv.py`) as well as the data (`data.csv`) are located in the `inst/` folder of the package directory.

```
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.read_csv("inst/data.csv")
```

The idea is to [run the py-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60150956/attaching-python-script-while-building-r-package) when a R-function (`rfunction`) is called:

```
rfunction <- function() {
          reticulate::py_run_file(system.file("load_csv.py", package = "mypkg"))
}
```

After building the package and calling the r-function `rfunction()` I get the following error:

> Error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'inst/data.csv'

How can I resolve this error? Is there maybe a system call that I can place within the py-script (analogous to `system.file` in R)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about R, but I'm guessing this is caused by the python script not being executed in the expected directory.

I'm assuming your python file is located in the `inst` folder of your package. As a quick and dirty solution, you could try to get around this by modifying your script to something like

```py
import os
import pandas as pd 

datafile = os.sep.join((
    os.path.dirname(__file__), # this gives the directory in which the python file is located, i.e. <package>/inst/
    "data.csv"
))

my_df = pd.read_csv(datafile)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I tried your code but the error persists. It might be that the path needs to be communicated to R as well somehow (like in this [answer](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-source-a-python-file-that-imports-another-python-file-using-reticulate-in-an-r-package/156904)).

Comment: I may have made a bad assumption in thinking that the python file was in the root of your package. You might need to correct that (I'll edit the answer if it's the case). 
Have a look at the path in the error message. Does it contain a double `inst` ?

Comment: You are a genius, thank you very much! I removed the "inst" line from your code and it works.

Comment: happy to help! :)
I've updated the answer to reflect the fact that the python script is located in `inst`